# Progress DB: backup restore and query individual tables

Tags: backup, openedge, progress-db

Here is the use-case: we need to backup some of the tables from a client server, copy it to our servers, restore it, then running some queries using ODBC.

I managed to do this process for the entire database by using `probkup` for backup, `prorest` for restore and `proserve` to make it accessible for SQL queries.

However, some of the databases are big (> 8GB), so we are looking for a solution to do the backup for only the tables we need. I didn't find anything with the documentation of `probkup` how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress only supports full database backups.

To get the effect that you are looking for you could dump (export) the tables that you want and then load them into an empty database.

"proutil dump" and "proutil load" are where you want to start digging.

The details will vary depending on exactly what you want to do and what resources and capabilities you have available to you.

Another option would be to replicate the tables in question to a partial database.  Progress has a product called "pro2" that can help with that.  It is usually pointed at SQL targets but you could also point it at a Progress database.

Or, if you have programming skills, you could put together a solution using replication triggers (under the covers that's what pro2 does...)

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's a good start. I checked the documentation of `proutil` `dump` and seems like there is no option to for multiple tables. (I need about 20). Worst case scenario I'll make a script to loop all my tables and backup them one after another. The question is, let's say I have 20 files of tables dump, can I use the `load` option to create a new DB out of them, and then execute queries?

Comment: Dumping and loading is a complicated topic to discuss in full in this space ;)  But in brief: yes, proutil does one table at a time but you can script multiple simultaneous dumps if you want; load should load into a pre-built empty database (I would keep that in a probkup file and just restore the empty whenever I'm about to reload).  You *can* load in parallel but it is faster to load in series.  You will also need to do an index rebuild after loading and prior to running any queries. There are quite a few tips & tricks that  I have left out - go fishng at pugchallenge.org/downloads for ideas

Answer (score 1):

probkup and prorest are block-level programs and can't do a backup or restore by table.

To do what you're asking for, you'll need to do a dump the data from the source db's tables and then load it into the target db.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is simply to maintain a copy of the DB, you might also try incremental backups.  Depending upon your situation, that might speed things up a bit.

Other options include various forms of DB replication, which allow you to keep real- or near-real-time copies of your database.

- OpenEdge Replication.  With the correct license, you can do query-only access on the replication target, which is good for reporting and analysis.
- Third-party replication products.  These can be more flexible in terms of both target DBs and limiting the tables to be replicated.
- Home-grown replication (by copying and applying AI files).  This is not terribly complicated, but you have to factor the cost of doing the work and maintaining the system.  There are some scripts out there that can get you started.

Or, as Tom said, you can get clever with replication via triggers.